# How to create a generic instance based on it generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have two storages. The first is simple. The second add additional info to entity (meta). I want to write factory that create storage based on generic type of my entity. But i can't do it. I received a compilation error. Maybe i want some weird things and i should rewrite architecture. Also i tried to use reflection, but it also didn't work. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    interface IStorage<T>
    {
        void Save();
    }

    class Storage<T> : IStorage<T>
    {
        public virtual void Save()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Save");
        }
    }

    class StorageWithMeta<T> : Storage<T> where T : EntityWithMeta
    {
        public override void Save()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Save With Meta");
        }
    }

    abstract class EntityWithMeta
    {
    }

    class StorageFactory
    {
        public static IStorage<T> Create<T>()
        {
            if (typeof(EntityWithMeta).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
                return CreateWithMeta<T>(); //compilation error! (type T must be convertible to EntityWithMeta)

                //reflection based approach:
                //var methodInfo = typeof(StorageFactory).GetMethod("CreateWithMeta", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                //return (IStorage<T>) methodInfo.Invoke(null, null); //System.InvalidOperationException. ContainsGenericParameters is true
            }
            return new Storage<T>();
        }

        private static IStorage<T> CreateWithMeta<T>() where T : EntityWithMeta
        {
            return new StorageWithMeta<T>();
        }
    }

    class MyClass1
    {
    }

    class MyClass2 : EntityWithMeta
    {
    }

    class EntryPoint
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            StorageFactory.Create<MyClass1>().Save();//expected Save
            StorageFactory.Create<MyClass2>().Save();//expected Save With Meta
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `where T : EntityWithMeta` to `Create<T>` does not solve your problem?

Comment: @Pikoh No, he would get an compile error with `StorageFactory.Create<MyClass1>().Save();` because `MyClass1`does not derive from `EntityWithMeta`.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom you are right, don't know how I didn't notice that :)

Comment: Use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of the generic type. The compiler cannot guarantee that your T is assignable to EntityWithMeta (it knows not about your runtime check) which is why you get the message

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance(`what i should write here?`)

Comment: @Patrick Nope, it would not compile. Have a look at my first comment.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance<StorageWithMeta<T>>()` but if the compiler barks at that too (can't recall if it does but I think it might) then `(IStorage<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StorageWithMeta<>).MakeGenericType(new[]{typeof(T)}))`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, your answer works. Add your answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Which version worked? Sorry typing on a phone so can't actually check myself :p

Comment: The second. `return (IStorage<T>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StorageWithMeta<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));`

Comment: I updated my answer with a note about the reflection-based approach you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot guarantee that `T` is assignable to `EntityWithMeta`, despite your runtime check. In other words it has no idea what that `if` statement means in context. You can get around this by using [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Type.MakeGenericType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
return (IStorage<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StorageWithMeta<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
```

A note on your reflection based approach (which you commented out in the OP): the method `CreateWithMeta` is itself generic. The `MethodInfo` object you have is for a generic method definition.  You were on the right track but you have to create the constructed generic method using [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var methodInfo = typeof(StorageFactory).GetMethod("CreateWithMeta", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var constructedGeneric = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
return (IStorage<T>)constructedGeneric.Invoke(null, null);
```